# Sending only current date file in FTP Task in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ftp

I need help creating an expression that will upload only current day files from my R drive to the ftp location.

the files begin with current date eg. 20161229.BS50.DAT.

i tried using this "R:/KS/+REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,30)GETDATE(),1,10),"-","") as the expression

but it didnt work.

### TITLE: Expression Builder

Expression cannot be evaluated.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE%202010&ProdVer=10.0.40219.1&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.TaskUIFramework.TaskUIFrameworkSR&EvtID=FailToEvaluateExpression&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Attempt to parse the expression ""R:/KS/+REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,30)GETDATE(),1,10),"-","")"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzbV9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the quotes after the R:/KS/

```
"R:/KS/"+REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,30)GETDATE(),1,10),"-","")
```